# Access denied to a .tmp path

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I am trying to zip a file with DotNetZip library. I am reading path from a file and saving zip to that file. But program crashes and throws. This is my code:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
   zip.AddDirectory(dir + "\\OUTPUT_FOLDERS");

   StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(dir + "\\Tools\\SettingsForPath");
   string path = sr.ReadToEnd();
   sr.Close();

   zip.Save(path + "\\SavedZip.zip");
   Directory.Delete(dir + "\\OUTPUT_FOLDERS", true);
}
```

and here is my error:

```
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 'C:\Users\DotNetZip-nvan5kb5.tmp' is denied.
at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
at Ionic.Zip.SharedUtilities.CreateAndOpenUniqueTempFile(String dir, Stream& fs, String& filename)
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.get_WriteStream()
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
```

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to write to the `C:\Users` directory, and you don't have permission to do that.

Use `Path.GetTempPath()` to obtain the name of directory where you can write.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.gettemppath.aspx for more information.

You would use it as follows:

```
using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{
    zip.TempFileFolder = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath();

    // etc.
```

Comment: I am not entirely sure how and where should I use this.. Can you write an example?

Comment: It throws error. It says Access to the path is denied.

Comment: @orglce Which path? The temp path, or the one you save to with `zip.Save(path + "\\SavedZip.zip");` ?

Comment: I've got the same error with an ASP.NET application. The target folder and temp are full-access for everyone in attempt to get working so don't think it's that. Also, my code only fails when I try and create a multi-part zip using MaxOutputSegmentSize. Don't try and create segments and it works so the access denied is from somewhere else

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is in which directory your temporary files created you don't have permission. Try to set temporary folder like

```
zip.TempFileFolder = @"D:\tempfolder";
```

and when save use

```
zip.Save(@"D:\tempfolder\my.zip");
```

Comment: That folder may not exist. In fact, that drive may not exist. See my answer.

Comment: Yes. May be that's why i said try to set known folder using `TempFileFolder` property of `ZipFile` object.

Answer (score 0):

If the user should really have write access try to check if you have write priviliges via code before writing on disc.. Use System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name for your name..
If it really is just temporary use the temp folder as stated above

```
string path = @"c:\temp";
string NtAccountName = @"MyDomain\MyUserOrGroup";

DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
DirectorySecurity acl = di.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
AuthorizationRuleCollection rules = acl.GetAccessRules(true, true, typeof(NTAccount));

foreach (AuthorizationRule rule in rules)
{
 //If we find one that matches the identity we are looking for
 if (rule.IdentityReference.Value.Equals(NtAccountName,StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
  {
    //Cast to a FileSystemAccessRule to check for access rights
    if ((((FileSystemAccessRule)rule).FileSystemRights & FileSystemRights.WriteData)>0)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} has write access to {1}", NtAccountName, path));
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} does not have write access to {1}", NtAccountName, path));
    }
 }
}
```