# Access denied error message when creating multipart zip archive using DotNetZip

Tags: zip, dotnetzip

Example code:

```
Using Zip As ZipFile = New ZipFile()
    Zip.AddFile("E:\Projects\HOPS\HOPS v1.56\Website\Photos\Pubs.zip")
    Zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize = 20 * 1024 * 1024
    Zip.TempFileFolder = "E:\Temp\Photos\Temp"
    Zip.Save("E:\Temp\Photos\Archive.zip")
End Using
```

Generates the following error message:

> Access to the path is denied.

Comment out the Zip.MaxOutputSegmentSize line and the code works generating a single zip file. When it fails, it has managed to create the file .z01 file. I don't *think* it's a permissions problems on the target folder because I've given "Everyone" full access to try and get it working plus it's able to create it when not attempting to break into 20MB chunks.

The full error message is this:

> [UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path is denied.]
>   System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   +10556971    System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName) +351
>   Ionic.Zip.ZipSegmentedStream.TruncateBackward(UInt32 diskNumber, Int64
>   offset) +694    Ionic.Zip.ZipEntry.Write(Stream s) +1302
>   Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save() +1162    Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String
>   fileName) +366    PhotoImport.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   E:\Projects\HOPS\HOPS v1.56\Website\Pubs\PhotoImport.aspx.vb:48
>   System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
>   System.Web.UI.Control.OnLoad(EventArgs e) +132
>   System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive() +66
>   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +2428

Later - bit more information from Process Monitor:

> w3wp.exe CreateFile C:\Windows\System32\inetsrv   ACCESS DENIED

Hmm, why is it trying to write to that folder?

Comment: Cross reference with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21583512/access-denied-to-a-tmp-path

Comment: This is some permissions quirk in the ASP.NET environment as the same code runs fine as a console application